# Write in json file with Python

Tags: python, json

For a project I need to write in a json file with python but all I have already seen (json.dump) don't match with what I want to do...

I have a structure and I just want to add something inside.
I want to add a service with a input for example :

```
{
"Serial_011": "011",
"Servers_011":
    [
        {
            "hostname": "srv-a.11",
            "ipv4_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "services":
                [
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/1",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/2",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "hostname": "nsc-srv-b.11",
            "ipv4_address": "0.0.0.0",
            "services":
                [
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/3",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    },
                    {
                        "uri": "http://www.google.fr/4",
                        "expected_code": 200
                    }
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the JSON into an object, add your info to that object and serialize it again (with prettyprinting if needed).

Comment: Where I find this ? Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: https://www.google.com

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html ?

Comment: If you don't have a special file format then the usual way of adding something not-just-at-the-end is loading it, modifying it and then writing back the whole thing. (On large files you try to use a streaming approach)

Comment: I have already open the json with 'with open...' but ithe problem is for the writing

Comment: @M_S I've posted an answer for this issue. Can you try that? You can definitely use the `with` clause with my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep in mind 4 methods while I work with JSON objects in python.

- `json.dumps(<a python dict object>)` - gives a string representation of json formed out of the python dict object
- `json.dump( <a python dict object>,<file obj>)` - writes a json file in file object
- `json.loads(<a string>)` - reads a json object from a string
- `json.load(<a json file>)` - reads a json object from the file.

The next important thing to keep in mind is that `json`'s and `dict` in python are equivalent.

So let us say, the file contents reside inside a file `addThis.json`.
You have a already existing json object inside the file `existing.json`.

The below code should be able to do the job

```
import json

existing = json.load(open("/tmp/existing.json","r"))
addThis = json.load(open("/tmp/addThis.json","r"))

for key in addThis.keys():
     existing[key] = addThis[key]

json.dump(exist,open("/tmp/combined.json","w"),indent=4)
```

Edit:
Assuming the contents of the addThis is not in a file but is to be read from the console.

```
import json

existing = json.load(open("/tmp/existing.json","r"))

addThis = input()
# paste your json here.
# addThis is now simply a string of the json content of what you to add

addThis = json.loads(addThis) #converting a string to a json object.
# keep in mind we are using loads and not load

for key in addThis.keys():
     existing[key] = addThis[key]

json.dump(exist,open("/tmp/combined.json","w"),indent=4)
```

Comment: So in existing.json I will put the current json, in addThis.json I write what I want to add with an input() and the result will be conbined.json ?

Comment: To clarify, the contents (the one that is to be added) is to be read from input()?

Comment: @M_S I've added the code for reading the new json contents from `input()` as well. Please up vote and confirm the answer if this works. Thank you.

Comment: It's turn in loop... What is exist in json.dump ?

Comment: Could you be a little more clearer?

Comment: It's doing nothing and rest like that like in an infinite loop

Comment: Can you provide your work! I've tested this before I posted it. So for the requirements I have explained it works without any issues. Please be sure of what you want.